# MAKEFILE - copying/moving files in present directory to another folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix, makefile

I do this in my application

```
cat $(shell find $(MY_DIRECTORY) -name "*.filetype" -type f \( -path '.*/*/*' -prune -o -print \)) > $(MY_DIRECTORY)/files-concatenated.css
```

This succesfully concatenates all of the files in the present directory (excluding subdirectories - which is what I need)

but when I do this

```
    mv $(shell find $(MY_DIRECTORY) -name "*.filetype" -type f \( -path '.*/*/*' -prune -o -print \)) > $(MY_DIRECTORY)/files-collected
```

or this

```
    cp $(shell find $(MY_DIRECTORY) -name "*.filetype" -type f \( -path '.*/*/*' -prune -o -print \)) > $(MY_DIRECTORY)/files-collected
```

It will look everywhere (including subdirectories), how do I make this exclude the subdirectories too)

*Edit: I use

```
    mv $(shell find $(MY_DIRECTORY) -name "*.filetype" -type f \( -path '.*/*/*' -prune -o -print \)) $(MY_DIRECTORY)/files-collected
```

and

```
    cp $(shell find $(MY_DIRECTORY) -name "*.filetype" -type f \( -path '.*/*/*' -prune -o -print \)) $(MY_DIRECTORY)/files-collected
```

Comment: Changing the command outside the find cannot change what `find` returns. It can change what returns from find are valid for operation (as both `mv` and `cp` can do something meaningful with directories while `cat` cannot). What do you get if you run that `find` command by hand? Does it look like what you expect? Also neither `mv` nor `cp` write anything meaningful to stdout by default so your `>` redirection on those lines is incorrect.

Comment: @EtanReisner find my_directory/ -name ".filetype" -type f ( -path '.*/*/' -prune -o -print ) returns what I want (files only in the present directory)

Comment: @EtanReisner performing cat in the makefile will only concatenate those files, for some reason mv and cp look in subdirectories too, the > was a mistake, I don't have it in my original file

Comment: mv and cp don't look anywhere but at what you give them. If you give them the same arguments as cat they should operate on the same files. If you give cat a directory it will yell at you at ignore that argument. If you give mv/cp a directory it will mv/cp it. Can you show the output of find and what you get if you use `mv -v` or `cp -v`?

Comment: Also, if you want find to ignore all subdirectories wouldn't using `-maxdepth 1` be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the files in a single directory why are you doing all this crazy find stuff?  Can't you just write:

```
mv $(MY_DIRECTORY)/*.filetype $(MY_DIRECTORY)/files-collected
```

??